# How to perform a action on generic HwndWrapper

Tags: python, pywin32, pywinauto

Im trying to do a recorded action on a generic windows process with Click , but the generic wrapper click don't work.I'm missing something ? HwndWrapper is not a intialized object ?

Error:
generic_wrapper.click(button='left', pressed='', coords=(self.x, self.y), double=False, absolute=False)
TypeError: click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Code:

```py
class WindowAction:

    def __init__(self, action_type, button_actioned, referred_window, referred_process, x=0, y=0):
        self.stamp_action = datetime.now()
        self.action_type = action_type
        self.button = button_actioned
        self.referred_window = referred_window
        self.process = referred_process

        if action_type == ActionType.MOUSE:
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

    def do_action(self):
        referred_application = application.Application().connect(process=self.process.pid)
        window = referred_application.top_window()
        generic_wrapper = window.backend.generic_wrapper_class
        print(f'Doing Action: {(self.x, self.y)} on {self.process}')
        generic_wrapper.click(button='left', pressed='', coords=(self.x, self.y), double=False, absolute=False)
```

Comment: You don't need to create wrappers explicitly. Pywinauto has different way to instantiate wrappers. Please read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) about this concept.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `()` after the `window.backend.generic_wrapper_class` line. You're referencing the class itself, not creating an instance.

Comment: I tried, however a new error arises, and by the definition of the backend object:
self.generic_wrapper_class = generic_wrapper_class

only receives the element

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: generic_wrapper_class is a class attribute, i don't need to use () or i am wrong ?
i get from here
https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/de1b1a8603a5372ad1dbf4e2e4f06dd01250cbd9/pywinauto/backend.py#L50

Comment: What is the output if you try `print(generic_wrapper)`?

Comment: <class 'pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper'>